# stole in -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Four of our days of the week - Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday were named in honour of Anglo-Saxon gods, but they didn’t bother with Saturday, Sunday and Monday as they had all gone off for a long weekend.
>   While they were away, Christian missionaries **stole in** bringing with them leaflets about jumble sales and more Latin.
>   Christianity was a hit with the locals and made them much happier to take on funky new words like ‘martyr’, ‘bishop’ and ‘font’.

What does *stole in* mean?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steal?searchDictCode=all 
number 2

Comment: It is not "stole in / bringing" it is "stole / in bringing".

Comment: @Chenmunka No it isn't.

Comment: Usage in context: _"Stealin' stealin'
 Pretty mama don't you tell on me
 I'm stealin' back to my
 same old used-to-be"_  Bob Dylan, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHDNBuUeslk  Dylan isn't robbing anything, he is returning to the life he once lived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stole** is the past tense of **steal**.

Knowing this I was able to use Google to find a nice set of synonyms for **steal** - creep, sneak, slink, slide, slip, glide, tiptoe, sidle, edge.  Since **steal** is an irregular verb, it was not an obvious search. The humorous entry was accusing the the Christians of being sneaky, not of being thieves.

**Stole in** means that the missionaries slipped into town when no was looking. It is somewhat idiomatic.

It's interesting to note that four of the synonyms listed also have irregular past tenses - crept (or creeped), snuck (or sneaked), slunk (or slinked), slid (or slided). It's further interesting to note that my built-in spell-checker did not accept creeped, snuck, slinked or slided.  The English language is, if nothing else, constantly evolving.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, in your example it is the intransitive use of the verb **steal**, see the definition #2, [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steal):

> 2. To move, happen, or elapse stealthily or unobtrusively.

Consequently, your sentence reads:

> While they were away, Christian missionaries move in bringing with them leaflets about jumble sales and more Latin.

So, they **stole** in bringing with them, not they **stole in** bringing with them.